# CardView con Fragment es posible?

Tags: android

Estoy que intento mostrar un CardviewLayout dentro de una Fragment, pero no logro hacerlo, muestra el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                   at ibk.center.contact.demo.democontactcenteribk.adapter.ContactAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ContactAdapter.java:33)
                                                   at ibk.center.contact.demo.democontactcenteribk.adapter.ContactAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ContactAdapter.java:17)
```

Mi Clase ContactAdapter:

```
    private List<ContactInfo> contactList;

public ContactAdapter(List<ContactInfo> contactList) {
    this.contactList = contactList;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, int i) {
    ContactInfo ci = contactList.get(i);
    contactViewHolder.vName.setText(ci.name);
    contactViewHolder.vSurname.setText(ci.surname);
    contactViewHolder.vEmail.setText(ci.email);
    //contactViewHolder.vTitle.setText(ci.name + " " + ci.surname);
    contactViewHolder.vTitle.setText(ci.fechaEntrada);
    contactViewHolder.vSede.setText(ci.sede);
}

@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.
            from(viewGroup.getContext()).
            inflate(R.layout.activity_cardview, viewGroup, false);

    return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);
}

public static class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView vName;
    TextView vSurname;
    TextView vEmail;
    TextView vTitle;
    TextView vSede;

    public ContactViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        vName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        vSurname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtSurname);
        vEmail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        vTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        vSede = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtAdd);
    }
}
```

Y mi Fragment:

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    RecyclerView recList = (RecyclerView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cardList);
    recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recList.setLayoutManager(llm);

    ContactAdapter ca = new ContactAdapter(createList(30));
    recList.setAdapter(ca);
}
```

Ese codigo esta en el Fragment, pero el MainActivity no lo he modificado.

El menu lateral si logro mostrarlo y el fragment sin el CardView tambien, pero cuando le pongo el codigo es lo que me da ese error, creo que no lo encuentra en el view o algo por ahi o los controles

Me marca error en esta linea:

```
ci.name = sdfTiempo.format(unaFecha.getTime()).toString();
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, Gracias

Comment: Kenny revisa mi respuesta como explicación a este problema.

Answer (score 1):

Error mio, colocaba el código en el lugar incorrecto, no era en:

```
onViewCreated
```

si no en:

```
onCreateView
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Claro que es posible, en cuanto a tu error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null
>   object reference
>                                                      at ibk.center.contact.demo.democontactcenteribk.adapter.ContactAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ContactAdapter.java:33)
>                                                      at ibk.center.contact.demo.democontactcenteribk.adapter.ContactAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ContactAdapter.java:17)

Es ocasionado porque el TextView indicado y los demás elementos en el contenedor no se encuentran :

```
vName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        vSurname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtSurname);
        vEmail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        vTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
        vSede = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtAdd);
```

La inicialización de los contenedores debe realizarse en `onCreateView()`.

> Recuerda que **onCreateView() es el equivalente en el Fragment de
>    onCreate() para las Activities** y se ejecuta durante la creación de la
>   vista. **onViewCreated() se ejecuta después de que la vista fue creada.**